# Difference between saving data in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I can see two different ways of saving data to my database in CakePHP 3.x, one that works and one that doesn't. Other than the obvious, that I can't get one to work, why would you use one rather than the other, and can you tell why one of the ways isn't working for me?

Option 1: (not working)

```
$usersTable = TableRegistry::get('users');   
$user = $usersTable->newEntity();
$user = $usersTable->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
$usersTable->save()
```

This option gives the error,

```
Warning (4096): Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::save() must implement interface Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, none given, called in 
Notice (8): Undefined variable: entity [CORE\src\ORM\Table.php, line 1453]
```

Option 2: Does work

```
$user = $this->Users->newEntity();
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
$this->Users->save($user)
```

Comment: Omitting required arguments is of course not valid... so... wut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one obviously can't work as you are missing argument within save method:

```
$usersTable->save(); // invalid
$usersTable->save($user); // valid
```

And if i am saving data from users controller why to use TableRegistry ? I always prefer second one.Using TableRegistry is a bit slower process (may be by some microseconds or less).

Comment: Thanks - don't know how I missed that. Cake Documentation uses the two different methods but I can't find anywhere explaining the merits/differences between the two

Comment: @ChrisBull Where in the docs do you see such a usage? That would be invalid and should be fixed!

Comment: @ManoharKhadka If at all, using `TableRegistry` directly is faster than using the magic property accessor of the controller or `loadModel()`, which issues various additional function calls, and in the end, invokes `TableRegistry::get()` too. Relying on the magic property or `loadModel()` however is more convenient when it comes to unit testing, as it makes mocking easier, also it's easier to change the model factory for such calls.

Comment: @ndm thanks for the response , do you mean option 1 is faster that option 2..?

Comment: Of course it is, given that the other options do call `TableRegistry::get()` themselves there is no way that they would be faster than a direct call. Such microsecond differences however should be pretty unimportant, what's way more important are the advantages mentioned with regards to testing and maintainability.

Comment: @ndm - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html - so to summarise; use option 2?

Comment: @ChrisBull I couldn't find any usage of `save()` without the required argument in the linked docs. And I'm not sure what exactly you are referring to with option 2, now that there such a mix of topics here.